# How to securely map an element from an smaller domain to the other element in a large domain

Tags: public-key, provable-security, encoding

Problem: I have a small sized domain, say s-bit. It's clear that the probability for an adversary to guess an element is $ \frac{1}{2^s}$. I need to make the probability negligible. However, I need to use a public encoding (or mapping) techniques, so anybody can map its elements from an small sized domain to a big one.

Question: What techniques can I use?

Please note that encoded data is going to be computed, so public key encryption naively may not work, as different participants have different keys. Thus I'm wondering if there is any generic encoding technique that does not require any secret keys.

Comment: If the technique is public, what stops the adversary from running it herself?Typically the answer to that is a secret key, but you don't want to use secret keys. So, maybe there is no solution?

Comment: Anything wrong with simply: each user $j$ secretly chooses a 256-bit random secret key $K_j$, then computes the 256-bit $\operatorname{HMAC-SHA-256}(K_j,x)$ where $x$ is a $s$-bit element of the small domain? $\;$ Perhaps that does not match the "_public encoding_" requirement, even though the method is public?

Comment: @fgrieu the problem is that I need a deterministic function, so the output of the function should be the same for two identical elements drawn from small domain.

Comment: With the requirements as I understand them, and the addition that the encoding/mapping is a deterministic function (in addition to public), there is no solution, for precisely the reason given in [mikeazo's comment](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25219/555#comment57605_25219).

Comment: @fgrieu  Consider I have encrypted an element drawn from small domain as $v=Enc_{pk}(r \cdot e)$, where $Enc$ is Paillier encryption and $r$ is a random value, $r \stackrel{R}\leftarrow \mathbb{F}_p$, and $p$ is a prime number smaller than Paillier moduli $N$. My problem is to reduce the chance of adversary to eliminate $e$ from $v$, when it has access to $v$. You may say use a tag (or MAC) but the value $v$ is going to be randomized and then combined with some other value; therefore, we cannot keep the tag consistent with the these changes.

Comment: I have trouble relating the above comment to the question. $\;$ In particular, is the " _small sized domain_ " of the question that of $r$, $e$, or $v$ in the comment? Is the " _public encoding_ " of the question the " _Paillier encryption_ " of the comment? Also, what is meant by " _eliminate_ $e$ " in that comment? I suggest reformulation the question, incorporating the comment in a unified framework.

Comment: @fgrieu What in the comment is just an example, where the " magic mapping" can be used . All the mapping (encoding) and small domain are related to the element $e$. By eliminating I meant when an adversary knows the universe of $e$ it can compute $e^{-1}$ and homomorphically multiply $v$ by $e^{-1}$. It can succeed to eliminate that value with the probability I stated in the question.

Comment: The previous comment makes a convincing argument that if $e$ can be guessed, and $Enc_{pk}(r \cdot e)$ known, and $Enc_{pk}$ is homomorphic, and $e^{-1}$ in the sense of the homomorphism can be computed from $e$, then $Enc_{pk}(r)$ can be successfully guessed. While this is far from the question as written (which does not mention anything like homomorphic, or multiplication by $r$, or that this is random), my conclusion is that what's asked in question and comments can't be achieved.

Comment: @fgrieu "Permutation" may solve the problem. First compute $f(x)=x-e$. Then evaluate $f$ at some public x points: $X=(x_0,...,x_k)$ and this gives us $Y=(y_0,...,y_k)$.  Now we have $k$ different encoding of $e$. Permute the element in $Y$. Then do encryption, etc. Now for the adversary to remove the element it guessed, it needs to know the permutation too. If we pick a right permutation function and $k$, we can make the probability of its right guess, negligible.

Comment: @mikeazo Please, give me your idea about the above comment.